# Why do I get different scores from, what I think, is the same operation?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, pipeline, grid-search

I have a pipeline which consists of a feature union object (num_cat_union) and linear regression.

When I apply the feature union to my data and then gridsearch for linear regression I get a RMSE of 32760

However, when I run the pipeline with the SAME feature union and linear regression and grid search that, I get a RMSE of 91490

What could be going on here? Why the discrepancy?

```
num_pipeline = make_pipeline(NumSelector(), NumImputer())

cat_pipeline = make_pipeline(CatSelector(), CatImputer(), OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False))

num_cat_union = make_union(num_pipeline, cat_pipeline)

full_pipe = make_pipeline(num_cat_union, LinearRegression())

def model_metrics(model, params, scoring, X, y):
    grid = GridSearchCV(model, params, scoring=scoring, error_score=0)
    grid.fit(X, y)
    print('X:', X.shape)
    print('Best RMSE: ', np.sqrt(-grid.best_score_))
    print('Best parameters: ', grid.best_params_)
    print('Mean fit time: ', round(np.sqrt(grid.cv_results_['mean_fit_time'].mean()), 3))
    print('Mean scoring time: ', round(grid.cv_results_['mean_score_time'].mean(), 3))


#The following gives ~90000 RMSE

params = {'featureunion__pipeline-1__numimputer__strategy': ['mean', 'median']}

model_metrics(full_pipe, params, 'neg_mean_squared_error', housing, y)

#The following gives ~30000 RMSE (P.S. the default strategy for imputing is mean already)

X = num_cat_union.fit_transform(housing)
lin_params = {}

model_metrics(LinearRegression(), lin_params, 'neg_mean_squared_error', X, y)

#Shouldn't they give the same results??
```

Comment: Inside the pipeline in `GridSearchCV`, not the whole `housing` data is given at once. Its first splitted into train and test. But when you manually call `num_cat_union.fit_transform` the whole data is transformed which is then split into train and test in `GridSearchCV` and given to `LinearRegression()`. So your second code (manually fitting the union) is actually introducing `"data leakage"` with respect to your first code.

Comment: So I take it the first method is the correct one, the train and test set do not cheat off each other. You think that is all it is? Oh wow, it makes that much of a difference?

Comment: That's a big difference in results though. In terms of correctness, which method is sound? I have already split my data into train and test set before and housing is the training set. Why should I care about the supposed "data leakage" here? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Then show what's the performance of both your codes on your "already split test data".